# OSX "Connection Failed" error when connecting to a Windows 7 share

Tags: windows-7, networking, macos, network-shares, samba

I have a Windows 7 machine on my home network, which I use to share files with other machines on my network.  When I try to connect to this machine from my Mac, it will work for a little while, but then when I try to reconnect later, I get a "Connection Failed" error.  My Mac can still see the Windows machine on the network, but it can't access any of its shared folders.

Restarting the Windows machine usually seems to fix this problem, but it is obviously not the ideal solution.

How can I fix this permanently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you open up the Windows Event Viewer (you can search for it from the start menu), and go to `Windows Logs -> System`, you will probably see a list of `Error` events with source `srv` and event id `2017`.  The message should say:

> The server was unable to allocate from the system nonpaged pool because the server reached the configured limit for nonpaged pool allocations.

To fix this, you can allocate more memory to the session manager and fileserver services.  Open up the registry editor, and locate this key:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Memory Management`

Set the value of `LargeSystemCache` to `1` (create a new `DWORD` value if it does not exist).

Next, find the key:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters`

Set the value of `Size` to `3` (create a new `DWORD` value if it does not exist).

Restart the machine.

*Adapted from http://praetas.blogspot.com/2013/03/mac-osx-connection-failed-accessing.html*